# On click of button there should be empty cache & hard reload in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, browser-cache

Our web application is based on JavaScript and we want the feature that if user clicks on logout button there should be empty cache and hard reload. If we don't do it in our application it causes some issue.

As we can't explain this feature to each user.

Comment: Its very large application, suppose if user add some image or data and he/she logout and login again. Then user is not able to see new changes. Only after empty cache and hard referesh, user is able to see new changes

Comment: You need some mechanism for cache-busting elements which you expect to change frequently. That way you don't need to force a reload or attempt to clear the cache, the user will automatically see the updated elements on a normal refresh.

Comment: what do you mean by the mechanism for cache-busting elements?

Comment: Well generally it boils down to appending some random querystring to the end of the URL for any assets you're loading in page. This forces the browser to treat the asset as a new resource when you land on the page, so instead of fetching it from cache it will fetch the latest version from the server. How you achieve this is entirely dependent on your environment and is a very broad topic in itself which you'd need to research. You can also tweak cache-headers server-side which might help to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using :

```
location.reload(true);
```

[Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Comment: I don't know, you have to test it out. It should theoretically work though.

Comment: how can `location.reload`  clear cache ? It's just reload from server.

Comment: In the case of a hard reload the browser doesn't use anything in the cache. It is forced to redownload everything. I recommend you read more on a hard reload before downvoting.

Comment: you need something like cache buster man to clear the cache. In the documentation mentioned by you it is not saying that `location.reload(true)` will do hard relaod. It will just reload from server.

Comment: @Unknown can you give any example saying that it will do hard relaod ?

Comment: The mozilla documentation was linked. `location.reload(true)` means nothing will be loaded from the cache, instead from the server. Thus being a hard reload.

Comment: @sandyJoshi  I think you're just looking at what it says and not really thinking about what it does. At first glance "reload from the server" obviously doesn't say "hard reload". But when you look at what it actually does, you would know it does a hard reload.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161228/discussion-between-sandyjoshi-and-unknown).